# Simulating Gaussian Mixture signals

Tags: matlab, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am trying to simulate a signal produced from a GMM of 3 mixtures. Here's MATLAB code

```
mix1 = -0.4 + 0.01*randn(10000,1); 
mix2 = -5 + 0.02*randn(10000,1);
mix3 = 10 + 0.1*randn(10000,1);

gmm = mix1 + mix2 + mix3;

[f,x] = ksdensity(gmm);
plot(x,f)
```

I expected to see 3 mixtures (i.e. peaks), instead I see just one gaussian. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was confusing mathematical formula of GMM with its simulation.

It should be

```
gmm = [mix1 mix2 mix3]
```

instead of

```
gmm = mix1 + mix2 + mix3
```

which is just sum of gaussians which is again a gaussian.